# Why script that works from terminal doesn't work from XFce panel?

Tags: bash, xfce

I have this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

(sleep $(zenity --entry --text "How long") && beep)&
```

It works from the terminal but not from the XFce panel (activator). Zenity is executed but there is no sound. The beep looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

mpg123 -q /home/kuba/Pobrane/beep-6.mp3
```

Comment: What is the full path to this `beep`? What is the full path to `mpg123`? Try running them with their absolute paths. Does this help?

Comment: Change this to `(sleep $(zenity --entry --text "How long") && beep) &> /tmp/log.log &` and check the log.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski beep was located in `~/bin/` I think that the problem was that it was not in PATH for the non-interactive shell.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks, that did help, it gave an error about not finding the beep that was in the `~/bin/` directory.